# Using fnmatch() to test for permissions in level1.level2.level3

Tags: php, oop

I am currently looking into re-working a permissions system in PHP that was built a while ago. The current version has exact permissions so for Admin you would have the following permissions:

```
acl.manage.self
acl.manage.others
```

That would say the user has access to manage his own permissions, as-well as others.

However while working on some new applications, I attempted to tap into the current permissions system by giving myself access to my entire application via:

```
lst.*
```

That way I don't have to give myself a bunch `.view` `.manage` etc.

It seems as though the existing system does not understand the * wildcard. So I am sitting here trying to re-write the "has_permission"

So my current working test environment I have created a user with the following permissions:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "*" [1]=> string(15) "fake.permission" [2]=> string(27) "none.of.these.should.matter" }
```

Technically the only permission that matters is [0] which says I should have permission to do anything and everything I want.

I am at a loss as to how to implement this flow into my method:

```
function has_perm($perm){
    //if I am checking if I have the perm 'acl.manage.all'
    //This function should return true if I have any of the following:
    // *, acl.*, acl.manage.*, acl.manage.all   

    //exact check
    foreach($this->perms as $p){
        if($p===$perm){ return true; }
    }

}
```

any nudge in the right direction would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code returns true if the needed permission `$perm` exactly matches any of your permissions `$p`.

You just need to change it to return true if the needed permission `$perm` matches any of the [`fnmatch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) patterns `$p`.

Try this:

```
foreach($this->perms as $p) {
    if (fnmatch($p, $perm)) { return true; }
}
```

You don't need to keep the exact match check, because `fnmatch()` will still detect exact matches if your permissions don't contain wildcards.

Comment: Do I need to specify in the fnmatch patern that it needs to be in "hard.match.*soft-match" form ?

Comment: @HydraIO No, you should be able to just use `lst.*` or even `*` as a pattern.

Comment: works great, my question was more along the lines the best way to describe it would be in SQL I would use `LIKE %string% string% or %string` In this case does `fnmatch()` use a `string%` pattern?

Comment: A `*` in fnmatch() is the same as a `%` in SQL. I'm not sure what you're asking though.

Comment: that basically answers it, and the code you gave works as intended. Thank you very much, sorry I'm terrible at explaining :p